# Как определить, находится ли точка внутри сложной, неправильной векторной формы (SVG)?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Я более-менее новичок во всем этом. Я пытаюсь создать приложение с использованием SVG (я бы предпочел векторные фигуры, которые можно масштабировать без потери качества). Используя веб-технологии и позже перейдем на React-native.

Есть ли  какой-либо способ узнать, находится ли точка с координатами x, y и которая также будет определяться свойствами CSS `left` и `top` внутри очень сложной, неправильной векторной формы?

Я знаю, что мой вопрос полон ограничений, поэтому на него действительно сложно ответить, поэтому даже указание на правильную документацию было бы полезно.

PS: Я пробовал использовать метод `elementFromPoint()`, но он возвращает ограничивающий прямоугольник, который DOM помещает вокруг моего SVG. Это полностью противоречит моей цели, я бы хотел убедиться, что точка обнаруживается только в пределах SVG Paths и самой формы.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to detect if a point is inside complex, irregular vector shape (SVG)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67170772/7394871) от участника  [@Steve M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1779596/steve-m).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67170772/7394871

Comment: В рамках SVG  это сделать не возможно, что два ответа снизу доказывают, курсор можно а вот точку нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотя ответ не совсем по вопросу (проверка точки на нахождение внутри Path), но для `событий мыши`, например, можно пользоваться элементами SVG как обычными элементами HTML. Можно вешать слушатели непосредственно на сложную `<path>`.

```js
const path = document.querySelector('path');
const text = document.querySelector('p');

path.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
    text.textContent = 'Inside the path';
})

path.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    text.textContent = 'Outside the path';
})
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" height="100vh">
    <path d="M118 211c-5.88,0.89 -13.66,2 -20,2 -24.3,0 -44,-19.7 -44,-44 0,-24.3 19.7,-44 44,-44 6.92,0 11.95,1.33 18,2 9,1 29,-21 30,-29 0.4,-3.21 0.21,-5.2 -0.01,-5.82 -2.92,-8.14 -6.76,-19.68 -6.76,-28.34 0,-27.61 22.38,-50 50,-50 27.61,0 50,22.39 50,50 0,27.62 -22.39,50 -50,50 -10.27,0 -17.23,-2.84 -25.23,-3.84 -13.24,-1.66 -34,25 -31,32 2.8,6.54 9,16.92 9,27 0,9.96 -4.17,17.36 -8.61,25.12 -7.39,12.88 19.85,34.98 27.41,31.96 3.45,-1.37 7.25,-2.08 11.2,-2.08 17.12,0 31,13.88 31,31 0,17.12 -13.88,31 -31,31 -17.12,0 -31,-13.88 -31,-31 0,-4.74 1.73,-9.5 2.49,-14.02 0.84,-4.92 -10.48,-32.26 -25.49,-29.98z" fill="red"></path>
</svg>
<p style="position:fixed;top:0;right:10px">
Outside the path
</p>
```

Если не искать легких путей, то можно отрисовать `path` на скрытом `canvas` в правильном масштабе. А уже по событию мыши проверять `ctx.isPointInPath()`.
При разворачивании или прокрутке окна перемасштабирования не происходит. Можно добавить `window.onresize` и `.onscroll`.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const path_string = svg.querySelector('path').getAttribute('d');
const text = document.querySelector('p');

let rect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
let view_width = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ')[2];

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let w = canvas.width = rect.width;
let h = canvas.height = rect.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.scale(rect.width/view_width, rect.width/view_width);
let path = new Path2D(path_string);
ctx.fill(path);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', detectInPath);

function detectInPath(e){
    if(ctx.isPointInPath(path,e.clientX - rect.x, e.clientY - rect.y, 'evenodd')){
        text.textContent = 'IN path';
    } else {
        text.textContent = 'OUT of path';
    }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" height="100vh">
    <path d="M118 211c-5.88,0.89 -13.66,2 -20,2 -24.3,0 -44,-19.7 -44,-44 0,-24.3 19.7,-44 44,-44 6.92,0 11.95,1.33 18,2 9,1 29,-21 30,-29 0.4,-3.21 0.21,-5.2 -0.01,-5.82 -2.92,-8.14 -6.76,-19.68 -6.76,-28.34 0,-27.61 22.38,-50 50,-50 27.61,0 50,22.39 50,50 0,27.62 -22.39,50 -50,50 -10.27,0 -17.23,-2.84 -25.23,-3.84 -13.24,-1.66 -34,25 -31,32 2.8,6.54 9,16.92 9,27 0,9.96 -4.17,17.36 -8.61,25.12 -7.39,12.88 19.85,34.98 27.41,31.96 3.45,-1.37 7.25,-2.08 11.2,-2.08 17.12,0 31,13.88 31,31 0,17.12 -13.88,31 -31,31 -17.12,0 -31,-13.88 -31,-31 0,-4.74 1.73,-9.5 2.49,-14.02 0.84,-4.92 -10.48,-32.26 -25.49,-29.98z" fill="red"></path>
</svg>
<p style="position:fixed;top:0;right:10px">OUT of path</p>
```

Comment: Как минимум еще так можно определить нахождение точки внутри фигуры).

Answer (score 2):

Пока вы используете встроенные SVG, `elementFromPoint()` должен работать нормально:

```js
const shape = document.querySelector('#shape'),
      status = document.querySelector('#inout');

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    const x = e.clientX,
          y = e.clientY;
    
    if(document.elementFromPoint(x, y) === shape) {
        status.className = status.textContent = 'inside';
    }
    else {
        status.className = status.textContent = 'outside';
    }
});
```

```css
h2 { margin: 0; }

.inside { color: lime; }
.outside { color: red; }
```

```html
<h2>The cursor is: <span id="inout" class="outside">outside</span></h2>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="200">
    <path id="shape" d="M150,120  q26,75 -80,50  c-80,-25 -53,-125 -26,-125  c53,-25 107,-25 107,50  q107,-50 53,50 z"
          stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" stroke="limegreen" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172304/7394871) от участника  [@Sphinxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869660/sphinxxx).</sub>

Comment: Действительно работает в отличие от `isPointInFill()`, который никак не заработает у меня ни с `SVGPoint` ни с `DOMPoint.fromPoint`. Не работает и все тут. Хотя `isPointInPath()` в canvas отлично работает. Спасибо, `elementFromPoint()` решает вопрос!!!